# Want to pull variable info from a Comments section

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am querying a table that contains a comments section. The comments section can contain part numbers of variable lengths. If, within the comments section I ensure that the part numbers are wrapped in quotes ("partnumberA"), is it possible query that field to pull everything in between the quotes (even if the part numbers could vary in length)?

Production notes are stored in an NVARCHAR field. Here is some sample data:

3/6/2015 (blujo) - "3490-0001023-02" PO46709 Due 3/10 (RW24718)

Comment: Please provide DDL statement(s) and sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `substring` and `charindex` functions.

```
declare @Comments varchar(50)
set @Comments = '3/6/2015 (blujo) - "3490-0001023-02" PO46709 Due 3/10 (RW24718)'
select substring(@Comments,
                charindex('"',@Comments)+1,
                charindex('"',@Comments,
                    charindex('"',@Comments)+1)-charindex('"',@Comments)-1)
```

The first `charindex` finds the first quote and starts on the following character. The second and third `charindex` finds the next quote after the first.

Answer (score 0):

If the length of the part number is standard (say 6 characters), you could always try a `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX` mix:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Comments, CHARINDEX('"', Comments) - 1, CHARINDEX('"', Comments) + 6)
FROM Table
```

This would start your substring just before the first double quote, and go until it finds the last double quote.

Comment: The sample data provided returns `"3490-0001023-02" PO46709`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CROSS APPLY` to select the indices of successive occurences of the `"` character in your `NVARCHAR` field. Having these indices at hand, you can use `SUBSTRING` to extract the required part of the field:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ProductionNotes, First.x + 1, Second.x - First.x - 1) 
FROM MyTable
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('"', ProductionNotes)) AS First(x)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CHARINDEX('"', ProductionNotes, First.x + 1)) AS Second(x)
```

`First.x` is the index of the 1st occurence of `"` in `ProductionNotes` field. The second occurence is located by feeding the previous index + 1, i.e. `First.x + 1`, as the `start_location` of `CHARINDEX`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample using a variable. Of course your query would reference a table column instead:

```
declare @x varchar(256) = '3/6/2015 (blujo) - "3490-0001023-02" PO46709 Due 3/10 (RW24718)';
select
    substring(
        @x,
        charindex('"', @x) + 1, 
        charindex('"', @x, charindex('"', @x) + 1) - charindex('"', @x) - 1
   )
```